# How do I create a partial in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, partial-views

I cannot put it more simply. I just want a step-by-step guide of how to create a handlebars partial in ember.js. I cannot find a proper one anywhere!!

- Where should partials be saved?
- How do I pass arguments to a partial?
- Do I need an underscore at the beginning of my filename?
- How do I register the partial?
- What is the correct way to render a partial and what is the difference between `{{> partialname}}` and `{{partial partialname}}`

Comment: instead of asking a bunch of questions, try out a couple a stuff from the docs. You may not get a step by step tutorial but you will get bits and pieces which will eventually lead you to solving your problems. Your question doesnt show any effort from your part. Basically ur asking for a cook book. These may be the reasons someone downvoted ur question.

Comment: Ember docs do help, please avoid undermining their value. Although this is a good question despite lack of effort to compile it.

Comment: For anyone else finding this question, Ember seems to discourage partials in favor of components these days: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practice-when-to-use-components-partials-or-templates/10777 So maybe that's why partials aren't mentioned in the guides. (The Ember guides used to have a Templates -> Rendering with Helpers section, back in 1.x, and then the section was removed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{{partial 'templateName'}}` is an Ember aware helper. Please disregard Handlebar's partial syntax `{> name}` when working with Ember.

Partials used to need an underscore at the beginning of their name, although this limitation is no longer true (https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/1917)

Partials have access to current template context and they do not take arguments. Please use `{{render 'contextName' optionalContextData}}` for passing arguments.

Read docs from Ember v1.13 on [`render` vs `view` vs `partial` helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/rendering-with-helpers/).

Please be aware that partials will [soon be deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/449) in favour of [components](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/), which are the preferred solution.

You don't have to register partials and they can reside anywhere as long as Ember can find them as templates.

Comment: Can you elaborate this one?